# How to tell if cv axle is in all the way?

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, cv-axle

Just replaced axle on a passenger side 98 Honda Civic. This was my first time doing this job without any supervision so I’m a little unsure if the axle is all the way into the transmission.

I did feel it click but there looks to be a small gap just enough for a screw driver to slide in. When I rotate the hub by hand the axle rotates smoothly and I can hear the gears engage.

I installed the nut flush and hit it a few times with a hammer just to make sure it’s in all the way.

So I’m just curious what will happen if it’s not fully seated. Will the car drive? Make noise? Etc[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You say you felt a "click" - that's good.

Also, the shaft should have some clearance as the face of the shaft should not be on the seal otherwise it will wear a part of the seal not designed for that purpose.

Comment: So the little gap in the picture is normal?

Comment: I believe you did. I accidentally deleted that post